# React Native and i18next how load language from AsyncStorage in i18next.init?

Tags: react-native, i18next, asyncstorage

I develop multilingual (6 langs) react native mobile app.

I try to load user language from AsyncStorage at initialization i18next, but get an **error**:

```
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "app" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
```

**My code**

```
async function loadLanguage() {
  return await AsyncStorage.getItem('lang');
}

i18next
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    debug: CONFIG.i18NextDebug,
    lng: loadLanguage(),
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    compatibilityJSON: 'v3',
    supportedLngs: ['en', 'ru', 'de', 'cn', 'hi', 'ae'],
    resources: {
      en: enTranslate,
      ru: ruTranslate,
      de: deTranslate,
      cn: cnTranslate,
      hi: hiTranslate,
      ae: aeTranslate,
    },
  }
);
```

Please tell me how to fix this or how normal people do it)